# How to create a directive for disable all elements into div element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how to create a directive for disable all elements into div element ?

something like this :

```
<div div-disabled div-disabled-condition="state=='Stack'||state=='Over'||state=='Flow'">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="url"/>
  <div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="url"/>
  </div>
<div>
```

Is it possible? I have no idea .

```
     angular
    .module('uiRouterApp.ctrl.add', ['uiRouterApp.ctrl.customDirective'])
    .controller('addCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        '$location',
        '$stateParams',
        '$state',
        function ($scope, $location, $stateParams, $state) {
            $scope.state = {};
         }
    ]).directive('divDisabled', function () {
        return {
        scope: {
              divDisabledCondition: '@'
             },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        };
    });
```

**Update :**

please see this :

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 ng-isolate-scope" selected-object="SelectedAutoComplete" local-data="requirements.Item1" search-fields="NameFa,NameEn" title-field="NameFa" minlength="2" field-required="true" image-field="ImageUrl" disable-auto-compelete="response.State=='Success'||response.State=='Error'||response.State=='Warning'">

<div class="angucomplete-holder">
  <input id="_value" ng-model="searchStr" type="text" placeholder="select" class="form-control ng-dirty" ng-focus="resetHideResults()" ng-blur="hideResults()" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" ng-change="inputChangeHandler(searchStr)" ng-disabled="response.State=='Success'||response.State=='Error'||response.State=='Warning'" style=""> 

  <!-- ngIf: showDropdown -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

directive :

```
.directive('contentsDisabled', function() {
        return {
            compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
                var inputs = tElem.find('input');
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    inputs.attr('ng-disabled', tAttrs['disableAutoCompelete']);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

why When the `state` is 'Success' or 'Error' or 'Warning' Input not disabled ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a directive that alters its content during compile time by adding the condition. Something along these lines (untested):

```
module.directive('contentsDisabled', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
      var inputs = tElem.find('input');
      inputs.attr('ng-disabled', tAttrs['contentsDisabled']);
    }
  };
});
```

See a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6380/

This has the drawback that you just copy the expression from `contents-disabled` into `ng-disabled` attributes of any inputs - if somebody uses a directive that in turn creates `<input>` elements, you won't pick them up.

It'd be less fragile to get hold of the `FormController` instance and iterate through all its controls, but sadly AngularJS doesn't expose the controls in a form. Maybe file a feature request?

Comment: @Football-Is-My-Life I think it's just because you have a ton of typos in your code. See here for a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6380/

Comment: Could you share what is the reason of having empty cycle inside directive code (JsFiddle)?

Comment: I updated your approach for case when elements already have ng-disable attribute present: http://jsfiddle.net/4yvza3xp/1/

Answer (score 2):

You also can use a tag fieldset :

```
<form>
    <fieldset ng-disable="foo">
        <input name="the_one"/>
        <input name="the_second"/>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="the_thrid"/>
</form>
```

With this way, when the variable foo is TRUE, inputs "the_one" and "the_second" will be disabled.

Comment: fieldset disabling does not work in IE. (And safari, I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ng-disabled` on your required expression on each input?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

---

If you truly do want a grouping directive, use the `compile` function of the directive to insert the `ng-disabled` attribute on each child. Or use a paren't child directive to signify which children to apply the `ng-disabled` to.

Comment: Because I am using this : http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/. This is just a div element like this : `<div class="ng-isolate-scope" angucomplete-alt="" id="ex1" placeholder="Search countries" pause="100" selected-object="selectedCountry" local-data="countries" search-fields="name" title-field="name" minlength="1" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option to control enable/disable input field for angucomplete-alt.
http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/#example13