# Make a div disable on click radio button

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone" value="allSku" ng-model="formData.value">
        All SKUs
        </label> <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone" value="specificSku" ng-model="formData.value">
        Specific SKUs
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<label>Div2:</label>        
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone1" value="allSku"
        ng-model="formData.percenSku"> All SKUs
        </label> <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone1" value="specificSku"
        ng-model="formData.percenSku"> Specific SKUs
        </label>
    </div>
```

Hi.I have a problem in disabling a div.I have two div's (div1 and div2).If i click AllSku in div1 then div2 should totally disabled.Similarly if i click AllSku in div2 then div1 should be disabled.ng-disable not working with div.Please help:)

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZLGKv5zMTsMdPetHlcXs?p=preview

Comment: ng-disabled by default works in form elements only, you can use directives to disable every input in the div [Plunker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25822878/3283641)

Comment: @amansinghgusain no ng-disabled is not working

Comment: yes ng-disabled will not work in div, because it is not form element

Comment: @AnushaBayya did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

`<fieldset ng-disabled="formData.percenSku == 'allSku'">` on top of the `<div>` element as a wrapper.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<label>Div1:</label>      
<fieldset ng-disabled="formData.percenSku == 'allSku'">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone" value="allSku" ng-model="formData.value">
        All SKUs
        </label> <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone" value="specificSku" ng-model="formData.value">
        Specific SKUs
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<label>Div2:</label>   
<fieldset ng-disabled="formData.value == 'allSku'">     
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone1" value="allSku"
        ng-model="formData.percenSku"> All SKUs
        </label> <label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio"
        name="chooseone1" value="specificSku"
        ng-model="formData.percenSku"> Specific SKUs
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the div elements inside some element, `<fieldset>` is a good choice. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VpmbQdOl6bejguWJFOyX?p=preview) here or run below script.

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.formData= {};
  $scope.formData.value = null;
  $scope.formData.percenSku = null;
  
  $scope.resetDis = function () {
    $scope.formData.value = null;
  }
  $scope.resetDis2 = function () {
    $scope.formData.percenSku = null;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label>Div1:</label> {{formData.value}} <button ng-click="resetDis()">Reset Div1</button>
    <br /><br />
    <fieldset ng-disabled="formData.percenSku">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="allSku" ng-model="formData.value" />

        All SKUs
       </label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="chooseone" value="specificSku" ng-model="formData.value" />

        Specific SKUs
       </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <label>Div2:</label> {{formData.percenSku}} <button ng-click="resetDis2()">Reset Div2</button>
    <br /><br />
    <fieldset ng-disabled="formData.value">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="chooseone1" value="allSku" ng-model="formData.percenSku" />
 All SKUs
       </label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="chooseone1" value="specificSku" ng-model="formData.percenSku" />
 Specific SKUs
       </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add disable effect using css below:

```
.disableEffect {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Then all you need is to add the class to the label using ng-class directive. For e.g.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" 
       ng-class="{'disableEffect': formData.value == 'allSku'}">
       <input type="radio" name="chooseone1" value="allSku" ng-model="formData.percenSku"> All SKUs
```

This would disable the label. Please note that `pointer-events: none;` won't work in IE.

Please let know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.disableUnitsDiv = function(type) {        
        var el = document.getElementById("units");
        var all = el.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if(type === "allSku") {
            scope.formData.value = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
                all[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
                all[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }

    };
```

I gave the div id and retrieved elements and disable each html input.It worked:)